# Flying within Mexico with a baby; will a passport be needed?

Tags: passports, children, mexico

I recently went to Mexico in January when my baby was only 2 months, with only her birth certificate. We went on a bus and everything was okay. Upon returning to the US, there was no issue with crossing the border.

So I plan on taking another trip to Mexico and, while there, I want to fly from Cuidad Juarez to Guadalajara.

The father of my child doesn't want to sign her passport application. Is a passport required for her since she is still an infant, and we'll be flying only in Mexico?

Comment: Just in case it makes a difference, what citizenship are you and your baby? And her father?

Answer (score 9):

Two points here: does your baby need a passport and, with or without one, can you fly with her within Mexico.

Yes, even as an infant, from birth, US citizens need a passport to travel outside the country and, more importantly, to return to the US. You can't be denied entry but, without identification or other proof, re-entry can be time-consuming and stressful.

To fly within Mexico, an infant who is more than 30 days old, and is not a Mexican citizen or resident, needs a passport (and where applicable, a visa). For those who are citizens/residents, it requires Clave Única de Registro de Población (CURP).

You should refer to the terms and conditions of the airline on which you'll fly; for reference, [Viva Aerobus](https://www.vivaaerobus.com/en/info/terms-and-conditions) explains it all (conveniently in English, as my Spanish is solo asi asi).

Are these procedures always followed? No, but better to do it correctly, than to have difficulties and irritation, especially when travelling with a baby.

Yes, [US law does requires the signature of both parents](https://travel.state.gov/content/childabduction/en/preventing/passport-req.html) (or legal guardians). You should explain to the child's father that, rather than taking away his rights, it gives him greater protection, as it prevents the child being removed from the United States without his permission.

You might also suggest to him that he has an advantage with a [notarized parental consent letter](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1254/kw/1254/sno/1/session/). It would show not only who he his, the father of the child, but how to reach him and under what conditions he agrees to this trip.

For you, leaving the US by air with your child would require a passport. By land, while you should have the child's passport, absent that, you need to have the birth certificate, and a good bit of patience, as you may spend more than the usual time at the border during your return.

Comment: There are some errors here. While a passport is never a bad idea, US citizens do _not_ always need one to travel by land to Canada or Mexico. [The rules for what documents are acceptable](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative) include, for example, birth certificates for children under the age of 16.